# My dog … very high when he was younger

Tags: idiom-request

My dog … very high when he was younger.
A. could jump
B. might be able to jump
C. could have jumped
D. might have been able to jump
E. can not jump

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Shofi.  You've pasted a test type question here.  You need to show some effort or explain why this question is unclear to you.  Don't expect us to do your homework!